# Unpack refinery gems in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I tried rake gem:unpack but I get task not found. I would like to have refinery gems in my /vendor directory to be able to see the never ending views and partials and may be modify them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still learning how to do things the "Rails way", but I feel your need to have the files in a directory that's easy to see.  One command I found that will dump in vendor in the local project is `bundle install --deployment`.  You'll need to run this after initially doing a `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

run `bundle package`

more here: http://gembundler.com/bundle_package.html